# How to navigate to the next screen only if the App is working behind in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

there are two screens in this app, first one is "MainPage.xaml" and Second screen is the "SecondScreen.xaml". When I open my App, first it should show the "MainPage.xaml". In the MainPage if I press Enter_btn, it should travel to the SecondScreen. Now, if I come out of the App, the values should run behind(for running the App behind I've already enabled the IdleDetectionMode). The problem is, if I open the App again while the App is running behind - the App Should not start from the MainPage. It Should start from the SecondScreen, only if the App is running.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're searching for is [fast app resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> If the app is suspended and the user relaunches the app, such as by tapping on the app name in the app list or tapping the app’s primary Start Tile, by default the old instance of the app is terminated and a brand new instance of the app is created. This process is slower than resuming a suspended app and provides a different user experience. Windows Phone 8 introduces the ability for apps to request that user actions that would typically relaunch the app, such as tapping the app’s Start Tile, instead resume the suspended instance of the suspended app instance, if one exists. This feature is called Fast Resume.

To enable it, simply add `ActivationPolicy="Resume"` to the application manifest:

```
<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" ActivationPolicy="Resume"/>
```

Comment: The sample file in the link which u gav is what i need. Thank u Kookiz.

Answer (score 1):

> for running the App behind I've already enabled the IdleDetectionMode

`IdleDetectionMode` will only allow the app to keep executing when the lock screen is engadged.

On Windows Phone, when the user navigates away from an application, the application is suspended (its state is preserved in memory).

If you want code to keep running in background when the user navigates away, you need to use [Background Agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

If you want the app to resume when the user taps again on the App Tile, check out [Fast App Resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (Windows Phone 8 only)